# How to fix Dynamic Sql Error: -104; Token Unkown - using a subquery in the where clause to filter on max date

Tags: sql, subquery, firebird

I am trying to query a firebird database for the first time, and I keep getting a

```
Dynamic SQL Error -104; Token Unknown.
line 11, column 30; AS 
[SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544634] 
Error Code: 335544634
```

It seems to be a problem with the `WHERE` clause.  `CERT_DATE` is a `TIMESTAMP` datatype. Thanks!

I did try casting as `TIMESTAMP` thinking that could be the error, but I got the same results.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    EVENTS.DONE_BY_FNAME,
    CERTS.CERT_NUM,
    CERTS.CERT_DATE,
    CERTS.GAGE_SN,
    EVENTS.VENDOR

FROM EVENTS INNER JOIN CERTS ON CERTS.EVENT_NUM = EVENTS.EVENT_NUM
WHERE CERTS.CERT_DATE = 
        (SELECT MAX(Z.CERT_DATE)
                  FROM CERTS AS Z 
                  WHERE Z.EVENT_NUM = CERTS.EVENT_NUM
        )
```

Expected Results

```
DONE_BY_FNAME    CERT_NUM    CERT_DATE                GAGE_SN    VENDOR          
GRES             12308       2019-01-14 00:00:00.0    AI0186     NW WELDERS
```

Comment: The query looks reasonable.  Sometimes, retyping the query can fix things, because some hidden character is accidentally inlcuded.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try re-typing.  I am not concatenating; well not intentionally ;)  I am using a free trial of RazorSQL.  I normally use MSSQL Server.

Comment: Your error message should show you the column and row of the error and the specific token that is not allowed there. So read and put the WHOLE text of that error

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using? And please post the full error message, normally token unknown errors also have a line with the 'unknown' token that caused the error.

Comment: ahh.  yes, i forgot to include the column and row numbers in the error txt.  They are as follows:  ERROR: Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Token unknown - 
line 11, column 30; AS [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544634] 
Error Code: 335544634 
  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!  I learned today that I am using an ancient version of Firebird that is no longer supported, and the syntax I am accustomed to using is not the same.  Next step - upgrade to Firebird 2.0 or migrate to MSSQL.

Comment: @M.Coull I'd suggest that if you are going to upgrade, then upgrade to either 2.5 or 3.0. Firebird 2.0 is also no longer supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates you are using Firebird 1.5 or lower. The problem is that Firebird 1.5 and lower do not support `AS` to define table aliases.

In InterBase 6, Firebird 1 and Firebird 1.5, the `FROM` clause was defined as (from InterBase 6.0 Language Reference):

> ```
> FROM <tableref> [, <tableref> …]
>
> <tableref> = <joined_table> | table | view | procedure
>     [(<val> [, <val> …])] [alias]
> ```

As you can see, this syntax does not allow `AS` before the `alias` (otherwise it would have been `[[AS] alias]`). This support for the optional `AS` token was added in Firebird 2.0 as part of the [Derived Tables](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes207.html#dml-dsql-derived-tables) support.

As a short term solution, replace `CERTS AS Z` with `CERTS Z`.

You should really upgrade though: Firebird 1.5 is no longer supported (support was stopped almost 10 years ago!) and contains known security issues that were fixed in later Firebird releases.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I just inherited this Firebird database on Monday, and I have never had any experience with Firebird in the past.  I would have never figured that out on my own.  The plan is to migrate the data to a MSSQL database.

Comment: @M.Coull In that case it is a trade off. A lot of more advanced SQL features were added since 1.5 that could help when migrating, on the other hand just plain upgrading a 1.5 database to 2.0 or higher can run into some compatibility issues that you may not want to deal with if you are just doing a one-off migration.

Comment: @M.Coull In any case, I knew that `AS` should work, so it was a matter of trying older versions until I got the same error ;)

Comment: You are THE MAN!  Thanks again!

Comment: 1.5 to 2.0 changed a lot of Interbase non-standard quirks though towards more formal and informal SQL standards, and can break application. We have an internal self-made CRM that soon will die peacefully, it still uses BDE and FB 1.5 and it could not be moved even to 2.1. So while using 1.5 is really awful, it might not be that easy to migrate.